# Ubuntu 10.04 on white 13" macbook - Want Fn Keys out the way!

Tags: ubuntu, macbook

I use shortcuts like Alt+F1 through to Alt+F10 on Ubuntu regularly, now on when installing on Macbook I need to do stuff like Alt+Fn+F2 to launch the run command etc as Macbook specials binding (brightness/sound etc..) are bound to default F1-F10.

I want Apple drivers to be get out the way, if I want to change brightness I prefer to use Fn+F1 rather than them taking over default F1-F12 (non-prefixed) behaviour.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

this problem can be fixed rather easily.  Ubuntu's help pages have a few different solutions:

[Changing Function Key Behavior](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change%20Function%20Key%20behavior)

I'm using the rc.local method on my macbook, but I'm sure the others would work just as well.